# Var not being used in object.var

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('data');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:L" + data.length);
  range.sort(1);
  const people = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var name = data[i][0] + data[i][1];
    console.log(i);
    if (!people.name) {people.name = {rows: [i]};} else {people.name.rows.push(i)}

  }
  Logger.log(people);
}
```

What should I be doing differently? At the end, it logs `{name={rows=[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, ...]}}` instead of having an object for each name...?

In the sheet there's just a first name and last name on columns A and B, for around 80 rows.

Comment: You want `people[name]`. Right now you're writing to the object property "name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bracket syntax if you want to use dynamic names for properties: https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/2321/dynamic---variable-property-names

In your case:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('data');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:L" + data.length);
  range.sort(1);
  const people = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var name = data[i][0] + data[i][1];
    console.log(i);
    if (!people[name]) {people[name] = {rows: [i]};} else {people[name].rows.push(i)}

  }
  Logger.log(people);
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's it... Thanks

Comment: If that answered the question, please consider accepting it: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers